# Android Bitmap.createBitmap() fills heap

Tags: java, android, graphics

I need big Bitmap (6000x2000), so I create one:

```
Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444;
Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(6000, 2000, conf);
```

And then at the end of the method I recycle bm and set it to null.
But again, my heap grows every time my method is called. Every time until it throws OutOfMemoryError.

Comment: Can I just know what is the use of creating a bitmap of size 6000*2000 for a mobile screen. You can still reduce it which might reduce your OOM problem.

Comment: having good question : see my profile with first question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7006825/destroy-consume-memory-by-imageview

Comment: @Andro_Selva: I need better quality of the Bitmap so that when the View is zoomed it doesn't get nasty.

Comment: @nik What is the solution to the problem?

Comment: that is still open not yet end

Comment: Is this on a SurfaceView canvas?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that it can take a couple of GC cycles for a Bitmap to be properly released on Android before Android 3.x. Even if you call recycle() I believe the bitmap counts against your heap usage until at least the next GC. This is one of the very few situations where I would advise you to force a GC by calling System.gc(). You could also try use several smaller bitmaps.